XSS attack on a Boolean variable
Checkmarx is detecting XSS vulnerability on my code which contains a boolean variable is_Private_Label__c.
Is there any way to fix this issue as we can't add the JSENCODE here as the data type is Boolean or we can call this issue as a false positive?
Please refer to the code below in the attached screenshot.


Yes, this is a false positive. The output values of a Boolean value can only ever be true, false, or null.

thank you for your time
